# Object attribute Null/Empty check

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have following object and need to check empty/nullability before do something.

Object:

```
ObjectA = new ObjectA
{
    ObjectB = new ObjectB
    {
        attribute1 = "64072292046",
        attribute2 = "",
        attribute3 = null
    }
}
```

Code for check nullability and empty

Method I:

```
private bool checkDataExist(ObjectA myObject)
{
    return !myObject.ObjectB.attribute1.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() 
    || !myObject.ObjectB.attribute2.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() 
    || !myObject.ObjectB.attribute3.IsNullOrWhiteSpace();
}
```

Method II

```
private bool checkDataExist(ObjectA myObject)
{
    return (myObject.ObjectB.attribute1?? myObject.ObjectB.attribute2 ?? myObject.ObjectB.attribute3) != null;
}
```

In code readability point of view this is not great. Just wondering any other way to represent this as more human readable?

Comment: Note that .NET has [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/), and `attribute1`, `attribute2`, and `attribute3` in your code are either [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) or [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields). Also note that Method 2 and Method 1 aren't equivalent because Method 1 also considers empty strings (`""`).

Comment: Make sure you also check for null on `ObjectB` and `myObject` with null conditional operator: `myObject?.ObjectB?.attribute1.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encapsulate that logic into the classes itself and let it decide when it's valid.

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public ObjectB ObjectB { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        if (ObjectB == null) return false;
        return ObjectB.IsValid();
    }
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public string Attribute1 { get; set; }
    public string Attribute2 { get; set; }
    public string Attribute3 { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Attribute1) 
        || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Attribute2)
        || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Attribute3);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
var objA = new ObjectA
{
    ObjectB = new ObjectB
    {
         //init
    }
};

if(objA.IsValid())
    // do whatever
```

Comment: Thanks @John, edited to compile correctly and replaced `&&` with `||` to reflect OPs requirements

Comment: Just to note that, is that a good thing to have that as a property within the class rather than a method. Because it's just validation and not doing any specific work.